# jQuery for each div build some rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, foreach, row

I really need some help with the following:
I have an HTML grid, in which at the left side the objects are shown and for each object a row on the right:

[image]

What I want is with jQuery: for each object on the left, 8 items should be added in a row at the right side.

jQuery code so far:

```
var items = [],
    element = $('<div class="item"></div>');
    row = $("<div class='row'></div>");
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) { //clone the element in the loop
    items.push(element.clone());
}
$(".rightside").append(items);
```

[My working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justamir/xw8pvt7j/)

So the rows with the items should be build dynamicly with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each()` to iterate over `.object` elements.

```
$('.object').each(function(){
    element = $('<div class="item"></div>');
    row = $("<div class='row'></div>");
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        row.append(element.clone());
    }
    $('.rightside').append(row)
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xw8pvt7j/3/)**